# How can I repair this punctured pipe in my garden?

Tags: plumbing, repair, pipe, gardening

So I did a silly thing this weekend while digging out a tree root/stump... I managed to partially (1/3) cut through the buried pipe that runs down our garden to feed an outside tap. (Fortunately it is easy to isolate just this pipe!

**How can I fix the pipe?**

Is there something I can put over it or do I need to cut it completely and put some sort of joint in? If I need to put a joint in, what should I use? Is there any special considerations given its buried?
[image]

Comment: If it's a water pipe, basically you cut a piece out and replace it.  The color throws me off a bit, it looks more like electric conduit than water pipe, by USA standard at any rate.  Where on the planet (country) are you located?

Comment: @Tyson I'm in the UK, it's definitely a water pipe. Water came out of it when I cut it and it stopped coming out when I shut off the valve at the top of the garden :) it only feeds the tap at the bottom of the garden as far as I know.

Comment: On this side if the pond, there are [PVC repair couplings](http://www.homedepot.com/p/206698172) that are easier for the less experienced. You can also just cut out a section of pipe and replace it... Beware PVC gluing isn't a wiggle it to you get it right thing... It will weld the connector and pipe together in about 5 seconds.  That's why for the  less experienced the expandable repair kit is easier.

Comment: @Tyson is that the same as [this](http://www.screwfix.com/p/jg-speedfit-15rkp-slip-coupler-repair-kit-15mm-x-15mm/60242?kpid=60242&cm_mmc=Google-_-Product%2520Listing%2520Ads-_-Sales%2520Tracking-_-sales%2520tracking%2520url&gclid=CLvh9vvBotQCFdS7GwodlwYJwA&gclsrc=aw.ds&dclid=CIzUivzBotQCFVUg0wodV5oJbQ)?

Comment: All you need is that glue and a repair coupling.  Easy easy to do.  I'd buck up and do the glue.  It is interesting that your pipe is made for electrical conduit not water.  Huh.  Does a back flow device come with this...system?

Comment: And I am a bit disturbed with the logs beneath everything.  Why are they there?  Did you install them? You must realize these logs will eventually decompose and this entire area will drop, right?  I am also uncomfortable with this pipe installed between these logs.  Why is this happening?  Just asking.  Be a pity to have to deal with this area again when you have it open and available now.  Tell me the rationale here.

Comment: @stormy did you read the question at all? The wood you see is part of the tree root I was digging out. The pipe is a water pipe and it's being used to feed a garden tap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [Tyson's](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/53243/tyson) comments above and some reading online I figured out how to repair the pipe and even better...no leaks!

Turns out the pipe is a 20 mm [MDPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-density_polyethylene) pipe so it could be repaired by putting a joint in the pipe. This was done by cutting the pipe and trimming off the pierced section, then putting [pipe inserts](http://www.screwfix.com/p/floplast-pipe-inserts-20mm-10-pack/33270) into either end of the pipe. It could then be joined using a [straight pipe coupling](http://www.screwfix.com/p/floplast-straight-pipe-coupling-20mm-x-20mm/52696).

The pipe inserts are required to stop the pipe getting squeezed/crushed when pushing into and tightening the coupling.

Photos of the inserts and finished fix:

[image: Finished repair][image]

Answer (score 0):

In the US,  they make a repair piece that clamps over a cracked section of pipe. Check with your local hardware store to see if they make something like that. It's also very easy to simply cut that section out  and repair it with a piece of pipe and a couple of unions. As someone noted, you need to be fairly quick  when repairing PVC pipe because the glue sets up fairly quickly. Just get all your pieces together and have everything ready before you glue them.

Comment: Where has it been established that this is PVC? Looks much more like PEX as much as I can guess anything from a picture (certainly a color I'm used to seeing in PEX and not in PVC) - which can also be repaired, but glue won't do...it takes a repair coupling and appropriate clamps.

Comment: @Ecnerwal the pipe is MDPE.